# Tomcat encrypting Chinese words in URL,how to cancel it?

Tags: url, tomcat, escaping

For example:

> http://**localhost**:8080/myyouxi/upload/example.jpg

When I download the picture, it changes to:

> http://**localhost**:8080/myyouxi/upload/%E6%9A%97%E5%A4%9C%E9%AA%91%E5%A3%AB.jpg

Then it directs to  HTTP Status **404** - `/myyouxi/upload/%E6%9A%97%E5%A4%9C%E9%AA%91%E5%A3%AB.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because your connector is not configured to use UTF-8 to encode URIs. Make sure that `<Connector>` entries in `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml` have the `URIEncoding` attribute set to `UTF-8`, e.g.:

```
      <Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8080"
           connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```